# Use office-addin-dev-certs with react-scripts

Tags: ssl-certificate, create-react-app, react-scripts, self-signed-certificate, custom-react-scripts

We have been developing an office add-in with ReactJS. I have always been using `sudo PORT=8000 HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=localhost.crt SSL_KEY_FILE=localhost.key ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start` (see [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/)) to test the add-in in development.

I just learned that https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts/tree/master/packages/office-addin-dev-certs works well in development.

So does anyone know how to use office-addin-dev-certs in a project by react-scripts and create-react-app?

Comment: Why doesn't the previous way of generating the self-signed certificate work anymore? Could you be more specific? Do you need to create a new test certificate?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev the previous way of generating the self-signed certificate refers to another question of mine.